# Добавить свойство checked при условии vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Возник такой вопрос, есть дерево checkbox - ов (допустим их 3). Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на один checkbox у двух других тоже появилась галочка (т.е. тоже стал отмеченным) и при снятии с этих двух checkbox-ов у родителя галочка убиралась.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [ "Apple", "Google", "Microsoft" ],
    companies: [],
    checkedAll: false
  },
  methods: {
    checkAll: function() {
      this.companies = [];
      
      if (!this.checkedAll) {
        for (let key in this.items) {
          this.companies.push(this.items[key]);
        }
      }
    },
    checkUpdate: function() {
      if (this.companies.length === this.items.length) {
        this.checkedAll = true;
      } else {
        this.checkedAll = false;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="checkbox" v-on:click="checkAll()" v-model="checkedAll">Выбрать все
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in items">
      <input type="checkbox" v-bind:value='item' v-model="companies" v-on:change="checkUpdate()">{{ item }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span>Выбрано: {{ companies }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!